# submit button does not invoke the action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im using the following button which is working fine and invoke the action as expected,

**save button**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("edit", "user", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" id="actionbtn" value="Save"  name="buttonType" />

                </div>
            </div>
    }
```

**Check button**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Check", "User"))
{
    <input type="submit" id="btnConnect" value="Check"  />
    <span id='result'></span>
}
```

now when I add the following code that should add some text if the operation was successful or not ,**the save button does not invoke the action** ,what am I doing wrong here?

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
        // Cancel the default submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Perform the AJAX call
        var target = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(target, function(result) {
            // Check the value of  result
            if (result === "True") {
                // It was successful, make  result text green.
                $("#result").css('color', 'green').html("successful.");
            } else {
                // Otherwise, it failed, display as red.
                $("#result").css('color', 'red').html("Failed");
            }

        });
    });
```

i've try to remove e.preventDefault(); without sucess...

Comment: upper form is not submitted?

Comment: is ajax call sent????

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-the ajax call is not submited when i click on save button,its works just when I click on check button

Comment: have you checked console??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-when i click on save I got internal server error like follows :jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery-2.1.1.js:8623
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.1.js:8152
jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.1.js:8298
(anonymous function) Edit.js:69
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.js:4409
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-when I click on save I dont want the the code with the ajax will be called at all(just on check),how can I prevent it?

Comment: insternal server error means ajax call going your server side action has some error occured

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-when I click on save I dont want the the code with the ajax will be called at all(just on check),how can I prevent it?

Comment: You can prevent it by adding an ID to your form and add submit event handler only to needed form

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Check", "User",FormMethod.Post,  new { Id = "Form1" })

Comment: @i try it but I didnt success,can you please put example how to do that?im new to web dev...

Comment: @JohnJerrby see my answer. hope it helps out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check like this that form submitted via which button.

you have to do like this to restrict it:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
        // Cancel the default submission
        e.preventDefault();

 if($(this).find('input[type="submit"]').val() === "Check") // form submitted via Check button
 {
        // Perform the AJAX call
        var target = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(target, function(result) {
            // Check the value of  result
            if (result === "True") {
                // It was successful, make  result text green.
                $("#result").css('color', 'green').html("successful.");
            } else {
                // Otherwise, it failed, display as red.
                $("#result").css('color', 'red').html("Failed");
            }

        });
}
else
{
// form submitted from Save button
}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add ID to your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Check", "User",FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "CheckForm" })
```

Then you need to add submit event handler only to form that needed:

```
$("#CheckForm").submit(function (e) {
    // Cancel the default submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // Perform the AJAX call
    var target = $(this).attr('action');
    $.post(target, function(result) {
        // Check the value of  result
        if (result === "True") {
            // It was successful, make  result text green.
            $("#result").css('color', 'green').html("Successful.");
        } else {
            // Otherwise, it failed, display as red.
            $("#result").css('color', 'red').html("Failed");
        }

    });
});
```

There is also another thing. When you make Ajax submit like this - then it will make submit of empty form. Is what you need?